# Some doubts about the reading of a file in Prolog using a Stream

Tags: prolog

I have a doubt about how work this simple Prolog Program that read character from a file and put these character into a list.

The code work well and is the following one:

```
readFile(FileInput, TextList):- open(FileInput, read, Stream),
                                readCharacter(Stream, TextList),
                                close(Stream),
                                !.


readCharacter(Stream,[]):- at_end_of_stream(Stream).    % Exit condition


readCharacter(Stream,[Char|Tail]):- get0(Stream,Char),
                                    readCharacter(Stream,Tail).
```

When **readFile/2** predicate is call happens that: the input passed file is open in read mode and that file is associated with a stream.

Then call the **readCharacter/2** predicate that take the Stream associated to my input file (the file to read) and the **TextList** that is the list where put the file content.

**readCharacter/2** predicate it is divided int two cases:

1) An exit condition that use **at_end_of_stream(Stream)** predicate that succeeds after the last character of the Stream (so the last character in the file) is read. In this case do nothing and the **readCharacter** predicate end

2) The second case is this rule that add a read character and ad it to my **TextList**:

```
readCharacter(Stream,[Char|Tail]):- get0(Stream,Char),
                                    readCharacter(Stream,Tail).
```

And here I have a doubt: it read a character from the Stream using **get0** and put it in the head of the list (as firs element of the list)...so...why the list don't contain the reverse of the file content?

i.e.

I have a file called **myFile.txt** that contains this text: **abc**

So **readCharacter** first read **a** character from the Stream and put it in the head of the list so I have:

**TextList = [a]**

Then **readCharacter** read **b** character from the Stream and put it in the head of the list si I have:

**TextList = [b,a]**

Then **readCharacter** read **c** character from the Stream and put it in the head of the list si I have:

**TextList = [c,b,a]**

If so TextList should contain the reverse content of myFile.txt file but it seems to me that TextList contain the same content of myFile.txt file in the same order.

Why? What am I missing? What is wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
readCharacter(Stream,[Char|Tail]):-
    get0(Stream,Char),
    readCharacter(Stream,Tail).
```

So you have your *Stream*, you get a character from it and unify it with *Char*. You have a yet-to-be initialized list in *Tail*. You then pass *Stream* (with one character now gone) and *Tail* to a recursive call of `readCharacter`. Rinse and repeat until *Stream* is at end of file.

The point is that this: `[Char|Tail]` means that *Char* is the head of the resulting list, or in other words, **before** everything else in the list.

If you trace this, you will see how *Char* gets unified with the codes of the characters you have in your file, in the order they are in the file, on calling `get0(Char)`, but disappear as you call `readCharacter` recursively.

Then, as you go out of the recursion, the character codes you got from `get0` magically reappear in the second argument of `readCharacter`, on the exit from the call in which they were read, each *Char* before everything in *Tail* (as should be, according to `[Char|Tail]`.

Basically, what is wrong with your reasoning (here and in other questions) is that you try too hard to impose your **expectations** on what you see instead of **accepting** and trying to **recognize the logic** in what you observe. Prolog, as all other man-made things, follows a certain logic, most of the time.

Comment: you're right, it was not difficult. Unfortunately I spent the whole night in the office today and I was quite melted

Comment: @false It's a rather silly question to start with, followed by my unnecessary, silly answer. The original question uses `get0/1`.